# Get Length of TStrings List in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, tlistbox

I have a TListBox called ListBoxPlayers, and I believe ListBoxPlayers.Items references the list of TStrings inside the TListBox. I am trying to use [this](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/classes/tstrings.count.html) function but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

EDIT:
So I'm trying to set the size of the TListBox dependent on how many strings it is going to display. Here's my code:

```
procedure TForm3.edtSearchChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBoxPlayers.Clear;
  if Length(edtSearch.text) > 0 then
     begin
        setSizeListBox((ListBoxPlayers.Items.Count));
        ListBoxPlayers.Visible:=true;
        dynamicSearch(edtSearch.Text)
     end
  else
     ListBoxPlayers.Visible:=false;
end;
```

`ListBoxPlayers.Items.Count` always stays at 0 however many items there are in the list.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work". Show your code.

Comment: It's always 0. I have updated with my code.

Comment: Haha I'm a moron. Forgot to remove the ListBoxPlayers.clear from the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the exact same as it appears, and the same way it works in Delphi:

```
NumberOfItems := ListBoxPlayers.Items.Count;
```

For looping:

```
for i := 0 to ListBoxPlayers.Items.Count - 1 do
```

Or

```
for i := 0 to Pred(ListBoxPlayers.Items.Count) do
```